# Kotlin annotations on delegated properties

Tags: android, annotations, kotlin

In Kotlin, is there a way to define an annotation on a delegated property (ex: `lazy`)?

```
class MyActivity: Activity() {

    @ColorInt
    val textColor: Int by lazy { ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.someColor) }
    ...
```

The IDE throws an error at the `@ColorInt` annotation:

> This annotation is not applicable to target 'member property with delegate'

Answer (score 27):

If annotating the getter is enough for you, you can use [annotation use-site target](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets), `@get:ColorInt`:

```
@get:ColorInt
val textColor: Int by lazy { ... }
```

Answer (score 27):

You can annotate the delegate with `@delegate`.

```
@delegate:ColorInt
val textColor: Int by lazy { ... }
```

From the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets):

> - `delegate` (the field storing the delegate instance for a delegated property).

Comment: I'm afraid that's not what OP wants: annotating the `@delegate:` target will refer to the field storing the `Lazy` instance in this case, while I believe it's the `textColor`'s `Int` that should be marked with `@ColorInt`.

Comment: @hotkey I have a feeling you are right, but figured I would put this in contrast to your answer in case it is actually what OP wanted or if others found this question.